# Separate background agent for a Windows Phone app to update live tile + lock screen independently

Tags: windows-phone-8, lockscreen, live-tile, background-agents, periodic-task

Is this possible? Or are Windows Phone 8 apps restricted to only a single background agent?

I currently have a background agent updating the live tile, and am pushing the memory constraints applicable to a Periodic Task as it is. If/when I add lock screen support whereby the lock screen needs to be updated as well in the background, must this be achieved via the same Periodic Task or can I have a separate background agent running just to update the lock screen?

Bardi

Answer (score 0):

You have only one BG agent available and then there is resource intensive task (which run when phone is charging I think) but that is not probably what you want.

BG agents *should* run every 30 minutes, so for example you can update lockscreen on odd runs and live tiles on even in case of memory problems.